# How to prepare data loaded data to display in UI intreface?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I receive data from the server - an array of categories: `interface Category {id: number, name: string, items: []}`

I want to create a group based on each category, because the category has `items: []`, so the group works like a dropdown element - it opens and hides on click.

Let's imagine the group is defined like this: `interface Group {id: number, name: string, elements: []}.`

Suppose in parent component I get categories:

```
public categories $: Observable <Category []>;
```

And in the template of this component I bring the categories into a group:

```
<app-category-group * ngFor = "let cat of categories $ | async"> </app-category-group>
```

How not to mix the **Category** and **Group** types? No matter what the content in the Group will be. Where to do this? In the parent after getting the categories to convert to another type `Group`? At the same time, I don't want to mutate the original data.

I have tried this:

**GroupsComponent:**

```
public categories$: Observable<Category[]>;
public categoriesGroup$: Observable<CategoryGroup[]>;

constructor() {
   this.categoriesGroup$ = this.categories.pipe((map(category) => {name:"Group1", items: category} as Group)
}

}
```

Inside **GroupsComponent** template:

```
<app-groups-component>
   <app-group-component *ngFor="let groupCategory of categoriesGroup$" [group]="groupCategory"></app-group-component>
</app-groups-component>
```

What do you think about that?

Comment: In place where you get data `public categories $: Observable <Category []>;` you can create a new object with type `Group[]` then use `Group[]` inside temaplte; Probably it is okay

Comment: Definitely block should not know about what is content you have. Block just must expand/callapse/toggle no more. So create a BlockModel { show: boolean, name: string, content: T}; And fill this object by data you recieve in component in your case it is Category. Or you can render directly `Category[]` but that is not universal solution. Tomorrow you have to render another type insibe toggable blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I tried to achieve what you wanted so far.

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9uvue9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgroup%2Fgroup.component.html)

I guess you don't need to mutate/modificate data if  you have convenient nested shape of data.

If you don't have convenient shape of data then you probably want to apply some groupBy logic or map data to the shape that fill projects needs.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it is what I need, so if I want aply Redux, should I save whole `<Category[]` in state? Or save only state of group?

Comment: Yes, I would store category array in the state.